# coloring in the rich text box in C#

Tags: c#

How, I can achieve this functionality when I write down something in rich text box and press space or enter key and then if it is a keyword( Void, main,if, else etc) then it should be in blue color. Means only thats word which is key word.
I have been made the functionality to achieved the word  which i am typing but not able to set the blue color.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simply switch to [Scintilla.Net](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) and set the lexer to the language you like (or write your own lexer)?